# filtering value of a grid by selecting dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I have a grid and dropdownlist.I want to filter values in a grid by the selection of dropdownlist.How Can i do this?
My code is like this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLVisitedVol" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="DsVisitedVol"
            DataTextField="VisitedVol" DataValueField="VisitedVol" 
            Width="244px">
        </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString=""
           ProviderName=""
            SelectCommand="SELECT [ID],[UserName], [Email], [visitedVol] FROM [HitTracker] where visitedVol=@VisitedVol ">
        <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="VisitedVol" Type="String"/>
        </SelectParameters>
```

How can i pass the selected value of dropdown list to @VisitedVol  .
If anyone knows pls help me.
tHANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

This is a same question?  I know i answered this earlier.

Use Control Parameter...

```
   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDLVisitedVol" Name="VisitedVol" PropertyName="SelectedValue"  Type="String"/>
```

Someone flag this as a duplicate....

[passing selected value of a dropdownlist to a parameter in aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584633/passing-selected-value-of-a-dropdownlist-to-a-parameter-in-aspx/2584677#2584677)